# in-App purchase:what all information need to send to android market in order to purchase an item?

Tags: android

I am implementing in-App purchase in my app.For purchasing an item in my product list what all data i need to sent to android market? Also should i send product_id for achieving this ? need help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation has a [good explanation](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html).